# How do I get this function to read the input properly?

Tags: python

I am having trouble with my monster_room function.  No matter what the input is, it will always choose the elif choice (elif choice > 5:...).  Here is the function:

```
def monster_room():
    print "This is the monster room! How many monsters do you see?"

    choice = raw_input("> ")

    if choice < 5:
        dead("More than that idiot!")
    elif choice > 5:
        print "More than you thought right?!"
        print "Do you go to the Alien room or Frankenstien room?"

        choice_one = raw_input("> ")

        if choice_one == "alien":
            alien_room()
        elif choice_one == "frankenstien":
            frankenstien_room()
        else:
            print "Type alien or frankenstien, DUMMY!"
            monster_room()
    else:
        print "Type a number!"
        monster_room()
```

How do I get it to read the input?  Also this is my first project and I know it's very basic and probably looks rough so other tips I am open to as well.  If you need the full code (99 lines) just let me know!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse your input data to a number type using `int()` because [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) returns a string.

```
choice = int(raw_input("> "))
```

As @Joran Beasley metniioned to be on the save side you shuld use a `try except` block:

```
try:
    choice = int(raw_input("> "))
except ValueError:
    print "Type a number!"
    monster_room()
```

Comment: note that user input of anything other than just digits will cause a crash

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Yes you are completely right! A `try` - `except` could solve this...

Comment: I am going to give the try function a...try HA thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Casting the input to `int` will solve it (it's a `string` when you use it). Do this:

```
choice = int(raw_input("> "))
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll get to the "type a number!" section even if you input 5 since you're not allowing a >= or <= scenario.

I do agree, though, you have to convert the input to an int or float.